# iOS 11 DropInteraction Session from Photos returns invalid file path

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop

When dropping images from the **Photos** app into my custom application, at `- (void)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction performDrop:(id<UIDropSession>)session`  I receive an `NSURL*` whose `[url absoluteString]` takes the following form:

```
file:///var/tmp/com.apple.DragUI.druid/.com.apple.DragUI.4tyFQQ/version=1&uuid=FF693BFB-99FF-4790-BBF2-A226593F718D&mode=compatible.png
```

Whenever I try to consume this file path, I receive a `The file couldn’t be opened because there is no such file` error. This makes sense, since the path itself doesn't look normal. I've seen [other implementations](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653993) that suggest it's possible that these should take a more expected path format.

Just in case the read issue was associated with access permissions, I can successfully wrap the operation with:

```
BOOL success = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource] /* begin */;

// ...

if (success) {
  [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource] /* terminate */;
}
```

However this doesn't impact on the response data. The application can currently also successfully read and write to the image gallery in other user journeys outside of Drag-and-Drop, so it doesn't appear to me to be related to missing permissions.

By contrast, I can handle `NSConcreteData` types that are passed from Brave Browser via `performDrop` without error.

Does anyone have an idea at what's happening? Is there any way that this provided URI can be normalized so that I can resolve the file correctly, or is it possibly indicative of an erroneous application state?

I'm running **iOS 14** on a physical **iPad**.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing directly from the url instead of trying to load it from `absoluteString`, like so:

```
// given an NSURL object `url`
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Edit:

`UIDropInteractionDelegate` implementation I'm using

```
- (BOOL)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction canHandleSession:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
    return [session canLoadObjectsOfClass:[UIImage class]];
}

- (UIDropProposal *)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction sessionDidUpdate:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
    return [[UIDropProposal alloc] initWithDropOperation:UIDropOperationCopy];
}

- (void)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction performDrop:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
    UIDragItem *item = session.items[0];
    NSArray *typeIdentifiers = item.itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers;
    [item.itemProvider loadFileRepresentationForTypeIdentifier:typeIdentifiers[0]
                                             completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable url,
                                                                 NSError * _Nullable error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            // use image...
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very for your help. Unfortunately this didn't work; the call to `dataWithContentsOfURL` returns `(null)`.

Comment: @Mapsy I updated my answer if you want to double check how you're implementing those delegate methods (tested dragging from Photos app)